# Use of variable in result_scan() snowflake stored procedure

Tags: variables, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to store the result of a last_query_id() as a variable and then later on in the stored procedure I am trying to use it in a table(result_scan()). I am coming across a number of errors when doing this, however I'm sure it's my level of knowledge of how snowflake works that s the problem. My code currently looks like this:

```
Declare query_id as varchar;
...
a number of queries;
...

query_id := (select last_query_id());
...
Some more queries
...

let c1 CURSOR for select * from table(result_scan(:query_id));
```

This is giving me an error saying result_scan() requires a string. I have tried using CAST to convert it to a string however this is not working either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The assignment is possible:

```
BEGIN
  LET query_id varchar;

  SELECT 1 AS c;

  query_id := (select last_query_id());

  RETURN :query_id;

END;
```

---

The [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html) function requires **string literal** so the following will not work:

```
DECLARE 
  query_id varchar;
  r INT;

BEGIN
   SELECT 1 AS c;

   query_id := (select last_query_id());
   
   LET c1 CURSOR for select * from table(result_scan(?));
   OPEN C1 USING(:query_id);
  
   FETCH c1 INTO r;
   
   RETURN r;
END;
```

---

A workaround could be usage of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and `RESULTSET`:

```
DECLARE
  rs RESULTSET;
  query_id VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 AS col1, 'a' AS col2;
  
  query_id := (SELECT last_query_id());
  
  let sql VARCHAR := 'select * from table(result_scan(''' || query_id || '''))';
 
  rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql);
  RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for assigning the result of a SELECT to a variable is

```
SELECT COL1 ... INTO variable
```

It's documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#setting-variables-to-the-results-of-a-select-statement)